# IOError - \xe2\x80\x8e\xe2\x81\

Tags: python, csv, io, ioerror

I'm trying to read a csv file as follows:

```
with open('‎⁨file.csv') as csv_file:
```

But, getting the following error:

```
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '\xe2\x80\x8e\xe2\x81\xa8file.csv'
```

I looked for a while, but was unable to solve the issue.

Any recommendations?

Thanks.

Comment: There is a `LEFT-TO-RIGHT MARK` and a `FIRST STRONG ISOLATE`  character between `'` and `f` for the argument, as `b'\xe2\x80\x8e\xe2\x81\xa8'.decode('utf8') == '\u200e\u2068'` and they being zero-width characters, they are not going to show up in the source code visually.

Comment: @metatoaster Thanks for your kind reply. What should I add to the code in this case?

Comment: Where does the name "file.csv" come from? Is it entered by the user?

Comment: @Simplicity: The solution is to avoid copying and pasting the file name from a garbage data source. Just select `'file.csv'` in the source code code, delete it, then manually retype it and the garbage should be gone.

Comment: Also, whatever editor you're using, either configure it to show you nonprintable characters in your source code, or, if it has no such setting, consider switching to a better editor.