# Unable to display image using matplotlib.pyplot on ipython project

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to run [FienSoP/canny_edge_detector](https://github.com/FienSoP/canny_edge_detector) code on github with my own directory. But instead of showing the figure it shows figure size().

canny_Edge_Detector.ipynb

```
%matplotlib inline
from utils import utils
import canny_edge_detector as ced

imgs = utils.load_data('⁨/Users⁩/office⁩/Mask_RCNN⁩/office/images')
utils.visualize(imgs, 'gray')
```

```
<Figure size 1440x2880 with 0 Axes>
```

util.py

```
import numpy as np
import skimage
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
import matplotlib.image as mpimg
import os
import scipy.misc as sm
import glob

def rgb2gray(rgb):

    r, g, b = rgb[:,:,0], rgb[:,:,1], rgb[:,:,2]
    gray = 0.2989 * r + 0.5870 * g + 0.1140 * b

    return gray

def load_data(dir_name):  
    imgs = []
    data_path = os.path.join(dir_name,'*g')
    files = glob.glob(data_path)
    for filename in files:
        img = mpimg.imread(filename)
        img = rgb2gray(img)
        imgs.append(img)
    return imgs


def visualize(imgs, format=None, gray=False):
    plt.figure(figsize=(20, 40))
    for i, img in enumerate(imgs):
        if img.shape[0] == 3:
            img = img.transpose(1,2,0)
        plt_idx = i+1
        plt.subplot(len(imgs), 1, plt_idx)
        plt.imshow(img, format)
    plt.show()
```

Since, I am a beginner described answers will be very helpful. Thank you in advance.

Comment: could you try a few things: 1. print(len(imgs)) (to see if there are actually images in you list). 2. print([a.shape for a in imgs])

Comment: 1. and 2. is showing it as empty. But the images are exist on the folder

Comment: ok, so your problem has to do with loading the images. Could you put print('files: {}'.format(files)) into the function load_data, under you glob.glob statement? Let's see if the files are found and not loaded correctly, or not found at all.

Comment: It gives a result as files: [ ]

Comment: so, the files are not found. Likely, there is a mistake in the data_path. Could you do print(data_path) after you create it, and compare it to the path to the folder that has your images?

Comment: Yes, they aren't. It gives me /\u2068Users\u2069/office/Mask_RCNN/\u2068office\u2069/images/\u2069/*g'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

copying the string

```
'/Users/office/Mask_RCNN/office/images'
```

that you provide in your question, directly from the question, into the python console, gives the following:

```
'\xe2\x81\xa8/Users\xe2\x81\xa9/office\xe2\x81\xa9/Mask_RCNN\xe2\x81\xa9/office/images'
```

So, the source that you originally copied this string from adds some zero-width characters, that are not  visible when you paste the string into a browser, but cause python to look for you data in a weird location. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51976847/ioerror-xe2-x80-x8e-xe2-x81) is a related problem.

You should be fine if you manually retype the string (or copy+paste the top string in my answer).

Answer (score 0):

Need to use `%matplotlib inline` with iPython

```
%matplotlib inline 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.plot([1,2,3])
```

See: [Plotting with Matplotlib](http://nbviewer.ipython.org/github/ipython/ipython/blob/1.x/examples/notebooks/Part%203%20-%20Plotting%20with%20Matplotlib.ipynb).

Comment: I have already used it on canny_Edge_Detector.ipynb. Are you asking me to add it on util.py file?

Comment: I used %matplotlib inline in the first cell of the notebook and it works.